# Angular 4.0.0 could not find bootstrap code

Tags: angular, angular2-modules

**Error** : Tried to find bootstrap code, but Specify either statically analyzable bootstrap code or pass in an entryModule to the plugins options.

main.ts

```
getHttp().get('/assets/config.json').toPromise()
 .then((res: Response) => {
 let conf = res.json();
 platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(createAppModule(conf));
})
```

I am using angular-cli. **With angular v2.3.1 this code was working fine.**

I want to fetch json and pass it to  @Ngmodules providers

```
{ provide: Config, useValue: conf }
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? just fetch json and pass it to ?....

Comment: I want to fetch json and want to pass it @Ngmodules providers { provide: Config, useValue: conf }

Comment: Is the JSON just an application configuration or `createAppModule()` creates different modules according to the values from the `conf` variable? Can you add that code to your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the data you are fetching from `config.json` are just about a configuration of an application module and you are trying to create a `Config` service to store them, I think the best would be to assign it to the `environment` and read it in your `Config` service later. The `environment` is available in `main.ts`, so no hacking (`createAppModule`) needed.

```
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { AppModule } from './app/';

getHttp().get('/assets/config.json').toPromise()
   .then((res: Response) => {
       let conf = res.json();
       environment.settings = conf;
       platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
});
```

You must also declare all new properties of `environment` in your `src/environments/environment.ts` file.

Comment: This doens't work if you want to use the config settings (say urls) in the configuration for imported modules. eg. 
`myFancyLib.forRoot({ backend: environment.backend })` :(

Answer (score 2):

The cli is attempting to use ahead of time compilation. Because of this, it needs to be able to find your main `NgModule`.

Usually the AOT compiler is able to do this statically just by looking for bootstrap calls. However you are not immediately bootstrapping, so the compiler needs you to explicitly tell it the name of your app module so it can compile it and all of it's components.

## Solutions

### `ng eject` and manually configure `entryModule`

The preferred solution is to tell the cli the name of your `entryModule`. This will allow AOT to work and give you all of it's benefits. However the cli does not currently support this(But there is a PR for adding an option [#4077](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/4077)).

The current workaround is to use `ng eject --aot` to switch to a manual webpack based build. Then you can configure your `entryModule` directly.

1. `ng eject --aot`
2. Open `webpack.config.js` and search for `new
   AotPlugin`

   - Add the following and replace your `AppModule` name
     `entryModule: 'path/to/app.module#AppModule'`

### Skip AOT

You can entirely skip this issue by using the `--no-aot` flag if you just need to get a build working. This isn't recommended as your app will be much slower and larger than it normally would(it will have to compile components at runtime and you will have to ship the compilier which is large).

`ng prod --no-aot`

Comment: actually you can specify the entry module alrady in the `tsconfig.json`... I'm doing it for quite a time already:
`  "angularCompilerOptions": {    "entryModule": "app/app/app.module#AppModule"  }`

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer didn't work for me.
Extracting the bootstrapModule part will let Angular find the bootstrap code.

```
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { AppModule } from './app/';

const bootstrap = () => {
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
};

getHttp().get('/assets/config.json').toPromise()
    .then((res: Response) => {
       let conf = res.json();
       environment.settings = conf;
       bootstrap();
});
```

Comment: My app does bootstrapping conditionally. This solved my problem and it seems logical too. Anyone opposed to this fix? Why is there no upvotes for this solution?